# Reference Android Library project from another android library project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library

I have an android library project (say A) in eclipse that is trying to reference another library project (say B). Both projects have res folders, and what I see is that A is unable to reference anything in B's res folder, basically R.java can't be resolved (no strings, no layouts etc).

Am I missing something crucial? Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just export one of your library projects as a jar file.

Then create a new folder name "libs"  (name is important) and then import that jar file into the project. As long as you've included the right files when creating the jar file, you should be able to reference those files from the second project.

Now when it comes to manipulating files in the res folder, that might get trickier.  If you are trying to do any UI stuff where the resources are in the library project, then I'm not sure if this is possible.

Hopefully this helps!

Cheers!

----------------------- Update ------------------------------

I'm not sure where you are going wrong. If you do what I suggested, make sure that you add the "gen" folder when creating the jar file. Then make sure you add the right import, and voila you can reference that file.

For example: say your library file has the package com.test.Test1

then in your gen folder you should have the package com.test.Test1 with your R.java file in it.

Export this project making sure to include that gen folder.

Then in your other project make sure you include "import com.test.Test1"

now in code you can just type R.Whatever. There might be some confusion if you are including another import for R.java.

Now if you want to access the "res" folder, I would imagine you could just change the res folder into a source folder (Build Path->Use as source folder) and then export the jar making sure to add the res folder.

Hopefully this works for you.
Cheers

Comment: Hey, so I'm a little confused here. I am already able to reference java code, so that is not really the issue. The issue here is specifically the <packagename>.R class. The library project marked as A in the question is unable to resolve that class, and I wasn't sure if there was a way to do this?

Comment: Hey, I've written up something that should get you where you want to go, but didn't have enough room in this comment, so I've just edited my answer above. Please check to see if this works for you.

Comment: You cannot export a library project to a JAR file

A library cannot be distributed as a binary file (such as a JAR file). This will be added in a future version of the SDK Tools.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full namespace before the R class. For example if the name space on project B is `com.projectB.*` then you can reference the R from project A by referencing R as

```
com.projectB.R.xxxx
```